# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote#admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote not found

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to create an enterprise application in the following environment (the one with Java EE, EJB and WAR modules). I'm following [these](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html) instructions (which are not about a web application though, I couldn't locate any article about a web application).

- NetBeans 7.2.1
- Glassfish Server 3.1.2 (containing the Servlet 3.0 API)
- EJB 3.1
- JPA 2.0
- JSF 2.1
- Oracle 10g

I have created a Class Library (New Project -> Java -> Java Class Library) to place remote (`javax.ejb.Remote`) interface(s) which is to be implemented by a stateless session bean. The Class Library has been added on the class path of both of the modules (EJB and WAR).

When an attempt is made to run this application, the following exception is caused.

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean transporterBean
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:211)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:81)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1118)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=managedbeans.TransporterBean/adminSessionBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote,refType=Session into class managedbeans.TransporterBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/managedbeans.TransporterBean/adminSessionBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
        at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:194)
        at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:205)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=managedbeans.TransporterBean/adminSessionBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote,refType=Session into class managedbeans.TransporterBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/managedbeans.TransporterBean/adminSessionBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:703)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:470)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:171)
        at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:184)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/managedbeans.TransporterBean/adminSessionBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=managedbeans.TransporterBean/adminSessionBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote#admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote#admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote#admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote not found]]]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:599)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=managedbeans.TransporterBean/adminSessionBeanRemote,Remote 3.x interface =admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote#admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote#admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote#admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote not found]]
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:191)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:776)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:744)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:169)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote#admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote#admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote not found]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:186)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote#admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote not found
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:248)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:215)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:119)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
        ... 70 more
```

---

The remote interface is as follows.

```
 package admin.sessionbeans;

import entities.Transporter;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote(AdminSessionBeanRemote.class)
public interface AdminSessionBeanRemote 
{
    public List<Transporter> getAllTransporters(); 
}
```

The stateless session bean.

```
package admin.sessionbeans;

import entities.Transporter;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless//(mappedName="adminSessionBean")
public class AdminSessionBean implements AdminSessionBeanRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="wagafashion-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Transporter> getAllTransporters() 
    {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Transporter.findAll").getResultList();
    }
}
```

The JSF managed bean.

```
package managedbeans;

import admin.sessionbeans.AdminSessionBeanRemote;
import entities.Transporter;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public final class TransporterBean 
{
    @EJB
    private AdminSessionBeanRemote adminSessionBeanRemote;
    private List<Transporter>transporters;

    public TransporterBean() 
    {

    }

    public List<Transporter> getTransporters()
    {
        transporters=adminSessionBeanRemote.getAllTransporters();
        return transporters;
    }

    public void setTransporters(List<Transporter> transporters) 
    {
        this.transporters = transporters;
    }
}
```

I have added all the **entity classes** to the Class Library according to [this comment](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=192634#c4).

> The client jar should contain the remote interfaces plus any classes
>   these interfaces depend on

---

A year or so ago, when I was working with NetBeans 6.9.1, I have developed some such applications. That version of IDE  doesn't mandate to place the remote interfaces in a separate Class Library.

I have NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 still installed on my PC and I have tried to create the same application (without a separate Class Library, the remote interfaces are in the same EJB module) and it worked as intended.

One last thing : when I remove this Class Library from both the modules (EJB and WAR) and deploy only the Java EE module (the one which is denoted by a triangle in NetBeans), it performs its intended function, retrieves data from the database and displays on the JSF page.

So, I'm very much confused about the cause of this exception and cannot say for sure whether it is because of Class Library problem or other required configurations that I'm likely to be missing (though presumably, there might be some JNDI look up problems that I don't know).

---

If someone had a link that says about how to create an enterprise web application in NetBeans 7.x, then it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that is wrong with your code is having a class name in your @Remote annotation. I'm very curious, why did you feel the need to put it there?

At any length, it shouldn't be there when
@Remote is used to mark a remote interface, and should definitely be removed.

Additionally, when injecting within the same JVM you should use an @Local interface or no interface at all (which has local semantics). Namely, you're now marshalling (serializing/deep copying) the return value every time the method is invoked and returns something. If these semantics are not needed it's quite a waste.

Comment: Originally that annotation was not like that in the question. It was made so by looking into an article. Additionally, I have created the application from scratch which doesn't have that name. The annotation is just like `@Remote`. The real thing is that it doesn't **even** work with `@Local` interfaces. I have tried it before asking the question.

Comment: I have referred to [this](http://randomthoughtsonjavaprogramming.blogspot.in/2011/10/creating-hello-world-in-netbeans-ide.html) and [this](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB) articles and tried to follow but no success.  I cannot imagine what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I have created the application once again from scratch deleting the connection pool, it works but cannot imagine the root cause of that exception. Thank you.